# Bash regex seems not to work on OS X

Tags: regex, bash, macos

I am trying to extract the name of a project from a file called `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

project 'forceios.xcodeproj'
target 'forceios' do

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'ART',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAdSupport',
    'RCTCameraRoll',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTPushNotification',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'RCTLinkingIOS'
]

pod 'SalesforceAnalytics', :path => '../node_modules/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'
pod 'SalesforceSDKCore', :path => '../node_modules/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'
pod 'SmartStore', :path => '../node_modules/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'
pod 'SmartSync', :path => '../node_modules/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'
pod 'SalesforceReact', :path => '../node_modules/SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'
pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'
pod 'react-native-maps', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
pod 'RNFS', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-fs'

end
```

with the following script, which outputs "No matches":

```
#!/bin/bash

input="`cat Podfile`"
regex1="project '(\w+).xcodeproj'"

if [[ "$input" =~ $regex1 ]]
then 
    name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "$name"
else
    echo "No matches"
fi
```

If I test the same text with the same regex with the script on http://regexraptor.net/ it matches the line containing
`project 'forceios.xcodeproj'` as expected. It does not work on my work mac. Is there something different about mac bash or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `\w+` is not valid ERE.

Comment: ...which is to say: Your "Regex Raptor" site is testing the wrong regex syntax.

Comment: BTW, ```input="`cat Podfile'"``` is quite inefficient: you're telling the shell to fork off a subprocess, execute `cat` in that subprocess, and read its output. Consider `input=$(<Podfile)`, which just tells the shell to directly read the file, no subprocesses involved. At *minimum*, use `input=$(cat Podfile)`, the modern (POSIX-specified, so standardized since the early 90s) command substitution syntax; it's far easier to nest than the 70s-era backtick syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `awk` to extract your data which is more suitable for processing file data:

```
awk -F"[ '.]+" '$1 == "project"{print $2}' Podfile

forceios
```

Answer (score 2):

`=~` relies on the local operating system C library's implementation of [POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) ("Extended Regular Expressions"). `\w` is a PCRE extension ("Perl-Compatible Regular Expressions"), and not part of this standard.

If you want alphanumerics to be considered valid, consider:

```
regex1="project '([[:alnum:]]+).xcodeproj'"
```